# MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath() is unclear

Tags: android, here-api

I'm assessing HERE Android SDK Premium v3.13.2_86.

In the `turn-by-turn-navigation` [sample](https://github.com/heremaps/here-android-sdk-examples/blob/bcb0fb18a33a14fef578fb1d7cf1bec87fa0bdd5/turn-by-turn-navigation/app/src/main/java/com/here/android/example/guidance/MapFragmentView.java#L95) there is a call `MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath()`. However the [API doc](https://developer.here.com/documentation/android-premium/api_reference_java/com/here/android/mpa/common/MapSettings.html#setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) says the method is deprecated:

> Deprecated. As of SDK 3.13. This method will be replaced with new one once shared map service feature is removed.
>   Method to allow switching of the disk cache to a separate service process and disk cache path.

So I am not sure whether I should use this method or not. What happens if I don't call it?

Of course, I'd like to have a map data cache in my app. And ideally it should be private to my app, so other apps (even those using HERE SDK) do not have access to the cache. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation and from the except you quoted, SDK 3.13 still supports shared map service so you have to keep using the `MapSettings.setIsolatedDiskCacheRootPath()` method until in a later release when shared map service feature is removed and a new method introduced.

Answer (score 1):

With SDK 3.16 it is proposed to use setDiskCacheRootPath instead

```
val diskCacheRoot = (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().path
                + File.separator + ".isolated-here-maps")
MapSettings.setDiskCacheRootPath(diskCacheRoot)
```